# How to update table value from Google search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-api

So I was challenged to make a table that its value is based on search result from Google. I was tasked with three things that's totally new for me:

1. For example, I have the name of Barrack Obama and Abraham Lincoln, when I click on Barrack Obama, the table (with three columns: Number, Page Title, and URL) will be updated according to the Google search result of "Barrack Obama" and when Abraham Lincoln is clicked, the table will be updated again accordingly.
2. I was asked to make the table changeable, must able to swap columns, resize, order it by ascending or descending.
3. and finally, when I click on the URL or any of the list, the result page could appear on the same page (on a reading panel, a different section from the table but still on the same page, let's say it's on the right side section of a webpage), and should be resize-able as well

Can somebody give me a pointer or clue on where should I start looking or doing? I was only given clue as using JSON, Jquery, or Google API, but I don't quite sure of the specifics. Any help is appreciated, sorry for the multiple question, I had to since it was related in some way (I think). Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Google does not have an API for their search results, but here's the general flow of logic:

You will need to make a GET AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest or jQuery on a Google search URL. Do some playing around with Google searches and you can see how they format them:

https://www.google.com/?#q=barack+obama

On the returned HTML page, you should parse out the results and set your table data. Again, play with the Google search results page and see how it's formatting.

For #3, the returned HTML object can be embedded in something like an iframe to give the user a reading panel.

For resizing, there aren't any default HTML tags that will resize like a split pane. If you decide to go with jQuery, you could look at the jQuery UI or other widgets that give you the resizing functionality you'd like.

Comment: thank you for the help, could you specify on the get ajax request? or could you point out some tutorial page related to my challenge, or something like that?

Comment: Here's the info on AJAX with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ If you just google ajax you'll find lots of tutorials and code samples explaining it more in-depth